# Resizable div puts textbox on new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here which allows you to resize the DIV and Textbox which stays at 100%.

However the textbox goes onto a new line - how can I keep the label and Textbox on the same line? So resizing the DIV around the label will reduce the textbox size?

```
<div id='div1' style='display:table-cell;width:300px; border: 1px solid black; white-space:nowrap; padding-right: 50px;'>
    <div style="display:table-cell"><label>Test&nbsp;</label>    </div>
        <input type='text' style='width:100%;' id='inputBox'/>

</div>

$("div").resizable({
    handles: "w, sw, ne, nw, se"
});
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XPUuj/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/xDHHM/

Your code had minor positioning problems and a unwanted div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <lable>Text</lable>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    border:#000 dashed 1px;
    display:table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:10px 50px 10px 10px;
}
input {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".container").resizable({
    handles: "w, sw, ne, nw, se"
});
```

Comment: Hi, Very close! I would like to also be able to resize between the label and textbox (to shrink either and expand the other) Thanks

Comment: Hi, are you saying that you want to change the space between the lable and input according to the size of the div?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the space between the label and the input. The div left and right sides would stay in the same position but the label and input would adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div around the label:

```
<div id='div1' style='display:table-cell;width:300px; border: 1px solid black; white-space:nowrap; padding-right: 50px;'>
   <label>Test&nbsp;</label>
   <input type='text' style='width:100%;' id='inputBox'/>

</div>
```

Jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/XPUuj/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should have your input inside the div

http://jsfiddle.net/XPUuj/3/

```
<div id='div1' style='display:table-cell;width:300px; border: 1px solid black; white-space:nowrap; padding-right: 50px;'>
    <div style="display:table-cell">$
       <label>Test&nbsp;</label>
       <input type='text' style='width:100%;' id='inputBox'/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```